# Independent arrays interfered with each other?

Tags: python, sorting

There's a given data set of two columns: **EmployeeCode** and **Surname**. 
The format is like:

```
EmployeeCode[1] = "L001" 
Surname[1] = "Pollard" 
EmployeeCode[2] = "L002" 
Surname[2] = "Wills"
...
```

What I was trying to do is to sort according to lexicographic order for each column so as to facilitate implementation of binary search later on.

This is my code:

```
#data set 
EmployeeCode, Surname = [0]*33, [0]*33
EmployeeCode[1] = "L001" 
Surname[1] = "Pollard" 
EmployeeCode[2] = "L002" 
Surname[2] = "Wills"
EmployeeCode[3] = "L007" 
Surname[3] = "Singh" 
EmployeeCode[4] = "L008" 
Surname[4] = "Yallop"
EmployeeCode[5] = "L009" 
Surname[5] = "Adams" 
EmployeeCode[6] = "L013" 
Surname[6] = "Davies"
EmployeeCode[7] = "L014" 
Surname[7] = "Patel" 
EmployeeCode[8] = "L021" 
Surname[8] = "Kelly"
EmployeeCode[9] = "S001" 
Surname[9] = "Ong" 
EmployeeCode[10] = "S002" 
Surname[10] = "Goh"
EmployeeCode[11] = "S003" 
Surname[11] = "Ong" 
EmployeeCode[12] = "S004" 
Surname[12] = "Ang"
EmployeeCode[13] = "S005" 
Surname[13] = "Wong" 
EmployeeCode[14] = "S006" 
Surname[14] = "Teo"
EmployeeCode[15] = "S007" 
Surname[15] = "Ho" 
EmployeeCode[16] = "S008" 
Surname[16] = "Chong"
EmployeeCode[17] = "S009" 
Surname[17] = "Low" 
EmployeeCode[18] = "S010" 
Surname[18] = "Sim"
EmployeeCode[19] = "S011" 
Surname[19] = "Tay" 
EmployeeCode[20] = "S012" 
Surname[20] = "Tay"
EmployeeCode[21] = "S013" 
Surname[21] = "Chia" 
EmployeeCode[22] = "S014" 
Surname[22] = "Tan"
EmployeeCode[23] = "S015" 
Surname[23] = "Yeo" 
EmployeeCode[24] = "S016" 
Surname[24] = "Lim"
EmployeeCode[25] = "S017" 
Surname[25] = "Tan" 
EmployeeCode[26] = "S018" 
Surname[26] = "Ng"
EmployeeCode[27] = "S018" 
Surname[27] = "Lim" 
EmployeeCode[28] = "S019" 
Surname[28] = "Toh"
EmployeeCode[29] = "N011" 
Surname[29] = "Morris" 
EmployeeCode[30] = "N013" 
Surname[30] = "Williams"
EmployeeCode[31] = "N016" 
Surname[31] = "Chua" 
EmployeeCode[32] = "N023" 
Surname[32] = "Wong"


#sort based on value of main array
def bubble_sort(main, second):
    sort = True
    passed = len(main)-1
    while sort:
        sort = False
        i = 2
        while i<= passed:
            #print(main[i],main[i-1],i)
            if main[i] < main[i-1]:
                main[i], main[i-1] = main[i-1], main[i]
                second[i], second[i-1] = second[i-1], second[i]
                sort = True
            i += 1
        passed -= 1
    return main,second



#main
#prepare sorted array for binary search
#for search by surname, sort according to surname
sName,sCode = bubble_sort(Surname,EmployeeCode) 


print("**BEFORE******")
for k in range(0,33):
    print(sName[k],sCode[k])
print("*BEFORE*******")

#for search by ECode, sort according to ECode
cCode,cName = bubble_sort(EmployeeCode, Surname)


print("**AFTER******")
for k in range(0,33):
    print(sName[k],sCode[k])
print("**AFTER******")
```

However, after the 2nd time sorting, the 1st time sorting result in **sName** and **sCode** just changed by themselves. I've never manually changed it.

BEFORE(1st sorting)

```
    **BEFORE******
0 0
Adams L009
Ang S004
Chia S013
Chong S008
Chua N016
Davies L013
Goh S002
Ho S007
Kelly L021
Lim S016
Lim S018
Low S009
Morris N011
Ng S018
Ong S001
Ong S003
Patel L014
Pollard L001
Sim S010
Singh L007
Tan S014
Tan S017
Tay S011
Tay S012
Teo S006
Toh S019
Williams N013
Wills L002
Wong S005
Wong N023
Yallop L008
Yeo S015
*BEFORE*******
```

AFTER(2nd sorting, see last 4 items)

```
    **AFTER******
0 0
Pollard L001
Wills L002
Singh L007
Yallop L008
Adams L009
Davies L013
Patel L014
Kelly L021
Morris N011
Williams N013
Chua N016
Wong N023
Ong S001
Goh S002
Ong S003
Ang S004
Wong S005
Teo S006
Ho S007
Chong S008
Low S009
Sim S010
Tay S011
Tay S012
Chia S013
Tan S014
Yeo S015
Lim S016
Tan S017
Lim S018
Ng S018
Toh S019
```

Can anyone tell me how could this happened?

Comment: What are your `EmployeeCode` and `Surname` objects?

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `sort`?

Answer (score 1):

Assignments and argument passing in Python won't ever create copies of objects. When you bubblesort your lists, the lists you pass into the bubble sort are the same exact list objects in memory as the lists the bubble sort passes back out. `Surname`, `sName`, and `cName` are the exact same objects, and when you do the second bubble sort, you modify `sName` and `sCode` instead of creating independent, sorted lists.

If you want to copy a list, you have to do so explicitly. This is a shallow copy:

```
new_list = original[:]
```

`new_list` will be a new list containing the same objects `original` contained.

This is a deep copy:

```
import copy
new_list = copy.deepcopy(original)
```

`new_list` will be a new list containing deep copies of the objects `original` contained. (This is sometimes *too* deep; for example, if you have a list of lists, you sometimes don't want to copy the objects inside the inner lists.)

Finally, I'd like to note that your initialization code is painfully verbose. You can use a list literal instead of creating a list full of zeros and assigning each element separately:

```
EmployeeCode = [
    'Pollard',
    'Wills',
    ...
]
```